# Accessibility of data using different APIs

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

Can I access the same data using different APIs?
Example: Can I insert the data using YCQL and read it using YEDIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is No. Even though the APIs share a common distributed document store, the data modeling and query constructs offered are significantly different. This means that the data inserted or managed by one API cannot be queried by the other API. More on this in the Note here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/introduction/#what-client-apis-are-supported-by-yugabyte-db